# AngularJS: Array.prototype.find() does not work in Chrome

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue where my angular code is working in firefox but not in chrome.

The browser console prints this:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at setSelectedColor (http://localhost:3000/assets/products/controllers/mens_detail_controller.js?body=1:24:54)
```

This is my controller (notice the `console.log`s at where the failure is happening):

```
app.controller('MensDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$controller', 'Product', function($scope, $resource, $controller, Product) {
  $controller('ProductsDetailCtrl', {$scope: $scope});

  $scope.init = function(id, locale, selected_color_id)
  {
    $scope.product = Product.get({productId: id, locale: locale}, function(data) {
      var unsorted_products_colors = data.products_colors.filter(function(product_color) {
        return product_color.mens == true;
      });

      $scope.products_colors = unsorted_products_colors.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.mens_sort_order > b.mens_sort_order;
      });

      setSelectedColor(selected_color_id);
    });

  }

  var setSelectedColor = function(selected_color_id) {
    console.log("ffff"); //prints
    if (selected_color_id) {
      console.log("eeeffff"); //prints
      // the error seems to happen at this next line, which is line 24:
      $scope.selected_color = $scope.products_colors.find(function(el) {
        return el.id == selected_color_id;
      });
    } else {
      console.log("hhffff");
      $scope.selected_color = $scope.products_colors[0];
    }
    console.log("ffffzzz"); // does NOT print

    $scope.selected_variant = $scope.selected_color.variants[0];
    $scope.sorted_product_images = $scope.selected_color.product_images.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.sort_order > b.sort_order;
    });
    $scope.selected_image = $scope.sorted_product_images[0];
  }


}]);
```

Why does it work completely fine on Firefox but not on Chrome? How would I fix this?

== UPDATE ==
Even when I print out the value of `$scope.products_colors` right before the crash, it prints out an object in my browser console:

```
ffff
eeeffff 
[Object]0: Object$$hashKey: "004"color: Objectcolor_id: 32created_at: "2014-08-12T19:47:32.000Z"id: 91mens: truemens_sort_order: 0product_id: 15product_images: Array[2]updated_at: "2014-08-12T19:47:32.000Z"variants: Array[1]womens: truewomens_sort_order: 0__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

== UPDATE 2 ==

Removing the `.find(...)` and replacing it with the array subscript fixes the error, but it's not fixing the bug because I need to grab elements with a certain attribute:

```
  var setSelectedColor = function(selected_color_id) {
    if (selected_color_id) {
      // $scope.selected_color = $scope.products_colors.find(function(el) {
      //         return el.id == selected_color_id;
      //       });
      $scope.selected_color = $scope.products_colors[0]
    } else {
      $scope.selected_color = $scope.products_colors[0];
    }

    $scope.selected_variant = $scope.selected_color.variants[0];
    $scope.sorted_product_images = $scope.selected_color.product_images.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.sort_order > b.sort_order;
    });
    $scope.selected_image = $scope.sorted_product_images[0];
  }
```

Comment: Probably change `var setSelectedColor = function(selected_color_id) {` to `function setSelectedColor (selected_color_id) {` When are you calling init? But is this code shown is exactly how it is?

Comment: Nope no luck... Yeh this is my exact controller code (except for the comments)

Comment: What is the value of $scopes.products_colors right before the crash? The error points to column 54, where you're calling `find`, so that can help you narrow it down... does $scopes.products_colors have a find property in both firefox and chrome?

Comment: Even though i posted the comment before, the variable still should have got instantiated to the function reference as your controller is instantiated, s what i said is wrong. Did you clear you chrome cache and try once.?

Comment: I tried on two different computers and neither of them worked. @Blackhole it says Yes for Chrome, so I don't get what's going on

Comment: When I remove the `.find(...)` line and replace it with `$scope.products_colors[0]` it works. Perhaps Chrome can't process `.find`? But the documentation says otherwise

Comment: find should be available with latest chrome, anyways you should check for compatibility when uing experimental technology. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Yeh but it's not working for me for both of my computers.. Is there an alternative to `find`?

Comment: It says that chrome doesn't support it (as of now)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing `.find` with `.filter(...)[0]`

Comment: Do not use filter, for finding just one item use array.some. filter will still iterate evenif it finds a match.