# Javascript: Alternative to Array.prototype.find()?

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue where `.find()` is not working on my Chrome browser when I use it in AngularJS. This was my original question: [AngularJS: Array.prototype.find() does not work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980985/angularjs-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-works-in-firefox-but-not-in)

It's failing on this line:

```
      console.log($scope.products_colors); // prints `[Object]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]concat: function concat() { [native code] }constructor: function Array() { [native code] }every: function every() { [native code] }filter: function filter() { [native code] }forEach: function forEach() { [native code] }indexOf: function indexOf() { [native code] }join: function join() { [native code] }lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf() { [native code] }length: 0map: function map() { [native code] }pop: function pop() { [native code] }push: function push() { [native code] }reduce: function reduce() { [native code] }reduceRight: function reduceRight() { [native code] }reverse: function reverse() { [native code] }shift: function shift() { [native code] }slice: function slice() { [native code] }some: function some() { [native code] }sort: function sort() { [native code] }splice: function splice() { [native code] }toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }toString: function toString() { [native code] }unshift: function unshift() { [native code] }__proto__: Object mens_detail_controller.js?body=1:24`

      $scope.selected_color = $scope.products_colors.find(function(el) {
        return el.id == 91;
      });
```

I know it's failing on `.find`, because the code works when I replace it with something else.

Is there an alternative to looking through an array and grabbing the first element with a certain condition in javascript?

Comment: `xs.filter(f)[0]`

Comment: Why not patch it in? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

Comment: Filter seems to work fine. Better than patching it in. Weird since docs say .find is compatible with chrome https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Why is `.filter()` better than patching it? It's potentially less efficient since it has to search the entire Array, whereas `.find()` stops as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: ...the MDN docs are wrong. Chrome may have it under an experimental flag, but they currently don't as a release since ECMAScript 6 isn't finalized yet.

Comment: Before 19 September, MDN was right. Then Bountin made [a wrong edit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find$compare?to=668997&from=662477).

Comment: @Oriol: Yeah, that happens a lot on MDN. I don't know why they don't have tighter control over who can edit. They end up with a good bit of bad information.

Comment: Well I don't need it to be scalable. It's only going to reach a maximum of 5 elements or so. Isn't worst case for both still O(n)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is [MDN's polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill):

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
```

Comment: I see that the MDN polyfill is broken. It's supposed to have a `i in list` condition before it invokes the callback.

Comment: ...or maybe not. The current draft doesn't have the *HasProperty* check that the other iterator methods do. That's weird. The current FF implementation does do the check though.

Comment: ...though the description states *"... **find** calls predicate once for each element present in the array..."*, so the check is implied. It's just not present in the algorithm.

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm not very used to ES6 yet so I'm not sure what you are talking about, but feel free to edit my answer (and MDN) if something is broken.

Comment: Your answer is fine since it reflects the current state of MDN, which reflects the current state of the spec (sort of), which is not finalized. It's just odd that they left the *HasProperty* check out of the algorithm. All the others, like `.forEach()`, `.filter()`, etc do the test, but `.find()` and `.findIndex()` don't show that step in the algorithm even though it's implied in the description. I'm guessing it'll be corrected eventually, at which point it'll be like: `if (i in this && predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {...`

Answer (score 18):

As pointed out by [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs) in the comments, `xs.filter(f)[0]` workes as an alternative to `xs.find(f)`.

Comment: what is xs sd and f ?

Comment: `xs` is the name of the array, `f` is the name of the function used to compare the elements of that array.

Comment: so basically we need to write down own logic to filter.

Comment: I know this is old but @Apoorv: You already hat to write down own logic to use "find", since the function requires a function as its parameter. But you can easily replace find with filter, since both functions have the same method signature. Filter returns an array, so simply access the first element. Find automatically returns the first found element.