# Js - Converting object data (WP-API)

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, api, object

Code after request:

```
var posts = [
  {  
    "id":268,
    "title":{  
       "rendered":"Koala"
    },
    "categories":[2]
  }
]

var categories = [  
  {  
    "id":2,
    "name":"Animals"
  },
  {  
    "id":3,
    "name":"Birds"
  },
]
```

Goal:
- Create a function that takes posts.categories value and replace it with matching id of categories.name.

Result:

```
var posts = [
  {  
    "id":268,
    "title":{  
       "rendered":"Koala"
    },
    "categories":["Animals"]
  }
]
```

I have searched around, but could not find a solution. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do that :

```
function setPostsCategories(posts, categories) {
  posts.forEach(function(post) {
    var cats = []
    post.categories.forEach(function(categorie) {     
      cats.push(categories.find(function(a) {
        return a.id == categorie
      }).name);
    })
    post.categories = cats
  })
  return posts
}

console.log("post",setPostsCategories(posts, categories));
```

See [demo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0xoxkjdq/). If you need to support IE, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981556/javascript-alternative-to-array-prototype-find) to define Array.find.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach would be to the ids of the categorie as location of the categories array.

```js
//Let the position be the corresponding id
var categories = [
  {
    "name":"Humans"
  },
  {
    "name":"Insects"
  },
  {
    "name":"Animals"
  },
  {
    "name":"Birds"
  },
]

var posts = [
  {  
    "id":268,
    "title":{  
       "rendered":"Koala"
    },
    // Requests all data from that categorie posistion
    "categories":categories[2]
  }
]

console.log(posts);
```

The approach you request is this:

```js
function FindId(obj, id) {
  let max = obj.length;
  // Loop to items.
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++)
    // Check if id is the same.
    if (obj[i]["id"] == id)
      // Returns right name.
      return obj[i]["name"];
}

var categories = [  
  {  
    "id":2,
    "name":"Animals"
  },
  {  
    "id":3,
    "name":"Birds"
  },
]

var posts = [
  {  
    "id":268,
    "title":{  
       "rendered":"Koala"
    },
    "categories":FindId(categories, 2)
  }
]

console.log(posts);
```